# Bayesian optimization for a Light GBM Model

Tags: python, pandas, bayesian, hyperparameters, lightgbm

I am able to successfully improve the performance of my XGBoost model through Bayesian optimization, but the best I can achieve through Bayesian optimization when using Light GBM (my preferred choice) is worse than what I was able to achieve by using it’s default hyper-parameters and following the standard early stopping approach.

When tuning via Bayesian optimization, I have been sure to include the algorithm’s default hyper-parameters in the search surface, for reference purposes.

The code below shows the RMSE from the Light GBM model with default hyper-parameters using seaborn’s diamonds dataframe as an example of my workings:

```
#pip install bayesian-optimization

import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import lightgbm as lgb
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization

df = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')

df["color"] = df["color"].astype('category')
df["color_cat"] = df["color"].cat.codes
df = df.drop(["color"],axis = 1)

df["cut"] = df["cut"].astype('category')
df["cut_cat"] = df["cut"].cat.codes
df = df.drop(["cut"],axis = 1)

df["clarity"] = df["clarity"].astype('category')
df["clarity_cat"] = df["clarity"].cat.codes
df = df.drop(["clarity"],axis = 1)

y = df['price']
X = df.drop(['price'], axis=1)

seed = 7
test_size = 0.3
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size,random_state=seed)

train_lgb = lgb.Dataset(X_train, y_train)
eval_lgb = lgb.Dataset(X_test, y_test, reference = train_lgb)

params = { 'objective': 'regression',
  'metric': 'RMSE',
  'learning_rate': 0.02}
lgb_reg = lgb.train(params, train_lgb, num_boost_round = 10000, early_stopping_rounds=50, verbose_eval = 100, valid_sets=eval_lgb)
```

Results

```
OUT:
Training until validation scores don't improve for 50 rounds.
Early stopping, best iteration is:
[1330 (n_estimators)] valid_0's rmse: 538.728
```

Here my attempt to implement Bayesian Optimization and the resulting RMSE values:

```
def modelFitter(colsampleByTree, subsample,maxDepth, num_leaves):   
    model = lgb.LGBMRegressor(learning_rate=0.02, n_estimators=10000, max_depth=maxDepth.astype("int32"), subsample=subsample, colsample_bytree=colsampleByTree,num_leaves=num_leaves.astype("int32"))

    evalSet  = [(X_test, y_test)]
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_metric="rmse", eval_set=evalSet, early_stopping_rounds=50, verbose=False)

    bestScore = model.best_score_[list(model.best_score_.keys())[0]]['rmse']

    return -bestScore

# Bounded region of parameter space
pbounds = {'colsampleByTree': (0.8,1.0), 'subsample': (0.8,1.0), 'maxDepth': (2,5), 'num_leaves': (24, 45)}

optimizer = BayesianOptimization(
    f=modelFitter,
    pbounds=pbounds,
    random_state=1)

optimizer.maximize(init_points=5,n_iter=5)  #n_iter=bayesian, init_points=random
```

Results

```
iter    |  target   | colsam... | maxDepth  | num_le... | subsample |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1        | -548.7    |  0.8834   |  4.161    |  24.0     |  0.8605   |
|  2        | -642.4    |  0.8294   |  2.277    |  27.91    |  0.8691   |
|  3        | -583.5    |  0.8794   |  3.616    |  32.8     |  0.937    |
|  4        | -548.7    |  0.8409   |  4.634    |  24.58    |  0.9341   |
|  5        | -583.5    |  0.8835   |  3.676    |  26.95    |  0.8396   |
|  6        | -548.7    |  0.8625   |  4.395    |  24.29    |  0.8968   |
|  7        | -548.7    |  0.8435   |  4.603    |  24.42    |  0.9298   |
|  8        | -551.5    |  0.9271   |  4.266    |  24.11    |  0.8035   |
|  9        | -548.7    |  0.8      |  4.11     |  24.08    |  1.0      |
|  10       | -548.7    |  0.8      |  4.44     |  24.45    |  0.9924   |
```

The RMSE (-1 x “target”) generated during Bayesian optimization should be better than that generated by the default values of LightGBM but I cannot achieve a better RMSE (looking for better/higher than -538.728 achieved through the above mentioned “normal” early stopping process).

The maxDepth and num_leaves should be integers; it looks like there is an open ticket to enforce this (i.e. bringing in “ptypes”): https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization/pull/131/files

Is there a reason why the Bayesian optimization doesn't seem to find a better solution with LightGBM but it does with XGBoost?

Comment: what's your coding related question? this looks like it belong to stats-exchange

Comment: Hi @Yuca - Is there something in my above mentioned code that is resulting in the Bayesian optimization not working?

Comment: please answer my question. then I can answer yours :)

Comment: @Yuca - I was hoping I had made some error in the code which could be corrected.

Comment: Hi @Yuca - I put this question on stats-exchange, but I got this from the moderators: "Put on hold as off-topic. This question appears to be off-topic because EITHER it is not about statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, or data visualization, OR it focuses on programming, debugging, or performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform.".  So it seems I am caught between the two.  If you know the answer, please can you share?

Comment: yeah, I sincerely thought you might have better chance there. I don't have an answer for you because it requires high specialization and lots of free time to answer, a rare commodity around here. So you might have to wait a lot of time or post in codereview

Comment: Did you try to fit a `LGBMRegressor` with default parameters and see the resulting metrics? The reason is that defaults for the native API (`lgb.train`) and the scikit-learn API (`LGBMRegressor`) might be different (they should not be, but I'm not sure authors provide any guarantees). Also , the default that you use in the native API is `max_depth=-1`, whereas your optimisation boundaries are different from that. Limiting the depth can lead to a different tree structure

Comment: Hi @ Mykhailo Lisovyi  - thanks for this - altering the max_depth within the pbounds works

Answer (score 0):

This question belongs on stats.SE; I would encourage you to ask on the Meta over there why it's not relevant. It might be a little too broad, as there might be a few possible reasons for the difference.

1) Double check that the hyperparameter space you're optimizing across is consistent in both models. (pbounds params seems only defined in LGBM model right now)

2) If the range of the search space is too small, there could be a local maxima at the default value, which is usually a heuristic, rule-of-thumb "pretty good" set of default values to start.

3) Both are Gradient Boost Models, but they have different ways of determining the best split value. This implies that your solution space may possibly develop different optimal values from the perspectives of the algorithms, which can only do a best-guess from their given architecture, and if the function to optimize changes, you might develop, by chance, a best-solution at the default LGBM hyperparameter values.

4) If you're looking at an extremely sub-optimal search space, similar to looking at a small subspace, you'll end up with mediocre results at max, which fall significantly short of the default settings. (It's like looking for the peak of a mountain in the ocean, whereas default might be some local hill.)

Answer (score 0):

For regression I managed to achieve improved results using the cv-function in the lightgbm package.

The "black box" function in my `BayesianOptimization()` returns the minimum of the l1-mean.

```
def black_box_lgbm():
    params = {...} #Your params here
    cv_results = lgb.cv(params, train_data, nfold=5, metrics='mae', verbose_eval = 200, stratified=False)
    return min(cv_results['l1-mean'])
```

after calling `maximize()` on the `BayesianOptimization()` and grabbing the result with the lowest l1-error I retrained a model and compared to defaults. This consistently results in lower MSE compared to defaults.